# "Unable to get exclusive lock" Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, updates

I'm trying to update my Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04, but get a pop up saying

```
"Unable to get exclusive lock"  
"This usually means that another package management application (like apt-get or aptitude) already running. Please close that application first"
```

What do I do?

Comment: like it says in the error message: make sure, there is no other apt-get running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are certain that you are not using Software Center or terminal to download anything, I would suggest trying to run the upgrade immediately after a reboot.

You could also try running the following command from the terminal:

`sudo do-release-upgrade`